# Java Runtime exec method throwing error when using with a custom URI

Tags: java, windows, runtime.exec, custom-url

I am running this command using my command prompt and it is running fine: without any issues:

`start demo:" -ping -ip 172.18.102.65"`

In the above command, `demo:` is a `custom uri` which I created and I am passing the parameters to that custom uri which are `-ping`, `-ip` and `<an_ip_address>` to make this `custom uri` work.

But when I run the same command using this code then it is not working:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"cmd.exe", "/c", "start", "demo:\" -ping -ip 172.18.102.65\""});
```

I am getting an error message: `Windows Cannot find '-ping'`

Please suggest how to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting my answer after your clarification of the question (thanks!).

This is the syntax that works for me:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"cmd.exe", "/c", "start demo:\" -ping -ip 172.18.102.65\""});
```

It seems that the code that parses the arguments in class java.lang.ProcessImpl interprets `\"` in a way that makes the resulting windows command line incorrect. Apparently, using the "start ..." as a single argument resolves that.

**Edit:** to make this URI work in Internet Explorer, you'll need to escape the double quotes according to URL encoding rules, thus you need to type the following in the address bar:

```
demo:%22 -ping -ip 172.18.102.65%22
```

where `%22` (hex value) represents the url encoding code for `"`

Comment: It would have been easier to understand if you had explained that in your question before I posted my answer. I see that you've added it now.

Comment: Since I cannot test your custom uri, could you at least show how the associated application or command is defined in the registry?

Comment: @user182944 see the new edit. If you need more, please ask a _new_ full-fledged question, not in a comment.

Comment: I have created a different thread on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26440188/custom-url-not-working-in-firefox-browser. Please check and let me know on your comments.